# PSTCollectionView layout error

Tags: ios, ios8

I'm using `PSTCollectionView` and it works perfectly with iPhone and iPad2 but in iPad Air it crashes in `setCollectionViewLayout`or in `prepareLayout`.

This is the error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_UITableViewCellSeparatorView prepareLayout]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff930da9600'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001120753f5 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000111d0ebb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011207c50d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111fd47fc ___forwarding___ + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111fd4398 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   los100primeros                      0x000000010f3278f1 -[PSTCollectionViewData prepareToLoadData] + 97
    6   los100primeros                      0x000000010f326aa9 -[PSTCollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:] + 73
    7   los100primeros                      0x000000010f2790d0 -[PSTCollectionView layoutSubviews] + 592
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000110645199 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 521
    9   QuartzCore                          0x000000010ffb0f98 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 150
    10  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ffa5bbe _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    11  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ffa5a2e _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    12  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ff13ade _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
    13  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ff14bea _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 390
    14  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ff15255 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 89
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111faa347 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111faa2a0 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111fa00d3 __CFRunLoopRun + 1123
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111f9fa06 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000113d349f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    20  UIKit                               0x00000001105cc550 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    21  los100primeros                      0x000000010f3740f3 main + 115
    22  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001126e0145 start + 1
    23  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
```

And this is the line on it crashes:

```
if (CGRectIsEmpty(self.bounds) || !_collectionViewFlags.doneFirstLayout) {
        _layout.collectionView = nil;
        _collectionViewData = [[PSTCollectionViewData alloc] initWithCollectionView:self layout:layout];
        layout.collectionView = self;  // HERE CRASHES
        _layout = layout;

        // originally the use method
        // _setNeedsVisibleCellsUpdate:withLayoutAttributes:
        // here with CellsUpdate set to YES and LayoutAttributes parameter set to NO
        // inside this method probably some flags are set and finally
        // setNeedsDisplay is called

        _collectionViewFlags.scheduledUpdateVisibleCells = YES;
        _collectionViewFlags.scheduledUpdateVisibleCellLayoutAttributes = NO;

        [self setNeedsDisplay];
```

Please I need help, I don't understand that problem. Thank you for advance.

**EDIT 1**

It crashes in iPad Air, iPhone 5s, iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus in iOS 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution has been to use UICollectionView.

Comment: Hi kova, to support ios5, I gonna use PSTCollectView right?

Comment: I don't know, I always support iOS 6, iOS7 or iOS8